# AddBoolOr and AddImplication in cp_sat solver

Tags: or-tools, constraint-programming, operations-research, cp-sat

Hi I have difficulty understand the following code, can anyone help to explain? Thanks in advance!

```py
model.AddBoolOr(x, y.Not(), b)
model.AddImplication(b, x)
model.AddImplication(b, y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely wrong. It should be `x.Not()` in the `AddBoolOr()`.

It encodes `b <=> x && y`.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Laurent's answer, let's assume that you want to encode `b <=> x && y`. One way of doing that is to split it up, and encode each direction separately:

1. Forwards: `b => x && y`. This constraint can be encoded as two constraints: `b => x` and `b => y`. In CP-SAT this is done via the following:

```
model.AddImplication(b, x)
model.AddImplication(b, y)
```

2. Backwards: `b <= x && y`. This can be rewritten as `not(x && y) || b` (check). The first term - `not(x && y)`, can be rewritten using De-Morgan's Laws as `not(x) || not(y)` so that the final expression to be encoded is `not (x) || not(y) || b`, which is done in CP-SAT like so:

```
model.AddBoolOr(x.Not(), y.Not(), b)
```

Notice that if `x = True` and `y = True` then the constraint will only be satisfied if `b = True`. Any other value of `x` and `y` will cause the constraint to be satisfied regardless of the value of `b` - so the constraint doesn't do anything in that case, as expected.

(Note: the implicit assumption is that `x`, `y`, and `b` are Boolean)

Comment: "The term x && y can be rewritten using De-Morgan's Laws as not(x || y)"
I thought it was:
not(x) && not(y) is the same as not(x || y), or,
x && y is the same as not(not(x) || not(y)) ?

Comment: Yep looks right now.